# Minimal Koszul-Tate resolutions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-resolution

In what generality of commutative associative algebras does there exist a *minimal* Koszul-Tate resolution? Or what is the most general condition known?

Comment: By minimal K-T resolution you mean a CDGA which as an algebra $\mathcal A$ is a polynomial algebra on a nonnegatively graded vector space and whose differential lands in $\mathcal A^+\cdot\mathcal A^+$ q-iso to your initial algebra $A$?